# How to update column by a long char in Oracle12c

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to update an HTML format, but the HTML format is too long to update. Furthermore, there are functions in this HTML format. it seems that Oracle recognized the characters as the replace() function

```
UPDATE DS_ADPRODSET_FREETAG
SET html='<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){function c(g){return g.replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;").replace(/"/g,"&quot;").replace(/'/g,"&#39;")}function b(h,n){var j={};var l=h.split(n);if(l.length!=2){return j}var m=l[1].split("&");for(var k=0;k<m.length;k++){var g=m[k].split("=");if(g.length==1){j[g[0]]=""}else{j[g[0]]=c(window.decodeURIComponent(g[1]))}}return j}function e(g){var h=/^(http:\/\/i\.yimg\.jp|https:\/\/s\.yimg\.jp)\/images\/listing\/tool\/yads\/yads-iframe.*\.html/;return h.test(g)}var a=(function(){v
ar k="14467902";var j;if(e(window.location.href)){j=window.location.href}else{try{if(e(window.parent.location.href)){j=window.parent.location.href}else{return k}}catch(i){return k}}var g=b(j,"?");if(typeof(g["sid"])!="undefined"&&g["sid"]!=""){return g["sid"]}var h=b(j,"#");if(typeof(h["sid"])!="undefined"&&h["sid"]!=""){return h["sid"]}return k})();var f=(location.protocol=="https:")?"https:":"http:";var d=f+"//yeas.yahoo.co.jp/a?f="+a+"&l=LREC2&p=jp&jcode=u&c=rp&domain=yimg.jp&rnd="+new Date()
.getTime();document.write("<sc"+'ript type="text/javascript" src="'+d+'">');document.write("</sc"+"ript>")})();
</script>'
WHERE adprodset_id=11111;
```

the Oracle asked me to replace the '&gt', but I just want the contents in  XXX  are characters.

Comment: Are you running this query in the command line? Normally (in a programming language) you would use a PreparedStatement to set the parameter values; you don't need to replace/escape anything, just set the value to anything you need.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. Maybe I expressed not clearly. I mean I wanted to update the contents in the HTML column no matter what it is. For example, UPDATE a SET html = 'balabalabala' WHERE id = 111; I just want to update 'balabalabala' to '<script type="text/javascript"> .......</script>'

Comment: The problem you are facing is most likely related to the tool you are using to run SQL statements. When using a command-line interface you'll need to escape some characters based on the command-line tool; when using JDBC/ODBC/etc you'll need to adhere to each one of these interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What follows `&` is recognised a substitution variable in IDEs like SQL developer and SQL* Plus

Add `SET DEFINE OFF` before running the query.

Checkout [this link](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/sqlplus-101-substitution-variables) to know more about substitution variable

Comment: thank you for your replay. I mean I want to update html column just in varchar quoted between ' '.